# How to require multiple permissions on a single broadcast?

Tags: android

I'm working on an android Service that allows other applications to collect data received from a company's proprietary devices. The connection can be made over Bluetooth or USB. I allow other applications to access this data through broadcasted intents sent out by the service. I would like to force applications to have the bluetooth permission as well as another permission for accessing our data before they can receive the intent. I know I can force BroadcastReceivers to have one permission to receive my Broadcasted intent using [sendBroadcast(Intent intent, String receiverPermission)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast%28android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.String%29) but how do I require the receiver to have more than one permission to see my Broadcast?

Thanks in advance.